# Spring boot security + spring boot Oauth2 UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, oauth-2.0, datasource

**Hello, I have an UnsatisfiedDependencyException, when I have the datasource in the AuthorizationServerConfig class. Can you tell me where the problem comes from.**
this my dataoursource class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:postgresql-ds.properties")
public final class DBConfing {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBConfing.class);

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DataSource dataSource = null;

    @Value("classpath:/db-script/hsql/kalanblow.sql")
    private Resource schemaScript;

    @Value("${init-db:false}")
    private String initDatabase;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(JdbcOperations.class)
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        try {
            Properties properties = DBConfing.getPropFromFile();

            org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource managerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            managerDataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
            managerDataSource.setSchema(properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.schema-name"));
            String str = properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
            managerDataSource.setUrl(str);
            managerDataSource.setUsername(properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
            managerDataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
            dataSource = (DataSource) managerDataSource;

        } catch (Exception ne) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to look up data source." + ne.getMessage());
        }

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean(name = "h2DataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() 
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        //ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        //databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/db-script/hsql/kalanblow.sql"));
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(initDatabase));
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }


    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript((org.springframework.core.io.Resource) schemaScript);;
        return populator;
    }

    @Bean
    private static Properties getPropFromFile() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Path myPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/postgresql-ds.properties");
        try {
            BufferedReader resourceAsStream = Files.newBufferedReader(myPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            properties.load(resourceAsStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info("get properties file fail ={}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return properties;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();

        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "ml.ciwarakalanblow.model" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

and this my AuthorizationServerConfig class:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.JdbcApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(final DataSource dataSource, final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final SecurityProperties securityProperties,
            final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
        return new JdbcApprovalStore(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {

        return tokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
            final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager).userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

}
```

**this is a sent message error Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}**

and the his decription:
**.AuthorizationServerConfig required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'dataSource' in 'JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' in 'XADataSourceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.**

this is my pom.xl file:

```
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.h2database</groupId> <artifactId>h2</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your gradle. Do you have spring data jpa available?

Comment: I add pom.xml file

Comment: Is there spring data jpa dependency in your pom.xml?

Comment: @ShababbKarim, yes for jpa dependency in my pom.xml: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem by declaring the dataSource parameters in the application.properties file instead of another properties file. Then I programmatically injected the dataSource.**